# How to enable a user to move an image of the screen in Windows Store 8?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have a simple direct question concerning Windows Store 8 apps.

Lets say i have a picture with a table on the screen. When the user presses the "edit" button he should now be able to move the picture on the screen to the desired position until he presses "done".

Which class do I need to use to implement that ? Also a simple code example in C# would be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to handle the ManipulationDelta events.  See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465387.aspx) for some examples of how to work with it.

Example...
XAML

```
<Rectangle Name="TestRectangle" Width="200" Height="200" Fill="Blue" ManipulationMode="All"/>
```

C#

```
private TranslateTransform dragTranslation;

// Constructor
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Add handler for the ManipulationDelta event
    TestRectangle.ManipulationDelta += Drag_ManipulationDelta;
    dragTranslation = new TranslateTransform();
    TestRectangle.RenderTransform = this.dragTranslation;
}

void Drag_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Move the rectangle.
    dragTranslation.X += e.Delta.Translation.X;
    dragTranslation.Y += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
}
```

Comment: hi can you tell me how to get the direction of the drag here?

Comment: The values of X and Y in e.Delta.Translation will give you all you need to calculate the direction.  Note that this is just delta information, though, so you might need to track the overall movement if you want to know the end position in relation to the start point.